# More efficient way to copy file line by line in python?

Tags: python, performance

I have 10GB file with that pattern:

```
Header,
header2,
header3,4
content
aaa, HO222222222222, AD, CE 
bbb, HO222222222222, AS, AE 
ccc, HO222222222222, AD, CE 
ddd, HO222222222222, BD, CE 
eee, HO222222222222, AD, CE 
fff, HO222222222222, BD, CE 
ggg, HO222222222222, AD, AE 
hhh, HO222222222222, AD, CE 
aaa, HO333333333333, AG, CE 
bbb, HO333333333333, AT, AE 
ccc, HO333333333333, AD, CT 
ddd, HO333333333333, BD, CE 
eee, HO333333333333, AD, CE 
fff, HO333333333333, BD, CE 
ggg, HO333333333333, AU, AE 
hhh, HO333333333333, AD, CE 
....
```

Let's say that in second column I have a ID. In whole files I have 4000 person and each have 50k records.

I can't use my prepared script for analysis on that big file (10GB - scripts in pandas, and I have too low memory. I know I should refactored it, and I working on it), so I need to divided that file to 4. But I can't split ID between files. I mean I can't have a part of one person in separate files.

So I write script. It divided file on 4 based on ID.

There is code:

```
file1 = open('file.txt', 'r')
count = 0
list_of_ids= set()
while True:
    if len(list_of_ids) < 1050:
        a = "out1.csv"
    elif (len(list_of_ids)) >= 1049 and (len(list_of_ids)) < 2100:
        a = "out2.csv"
    elif (len(list_of_ids)) >= 2099 and (len(list_of_ids)) < 3200:
        a = "out3.csv"
    else:
        a = "out4.csv"
        
    line = file1.readline()
 
    if not line:
        break
    
    try:
        
        list_of_ids.add(line.split(',')[1])
        out = open(a, "a")
        out.write(line)
        
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
    count += 1
    
 
    
out.close()
```

But it's sooooo slow, and I need to speed it up.
There is many if, and each time I open file, but I can't figure it out how to get better performance.
Maybe someone have some tips?

Comment: Your code currently doesn't do anything to keep records of the same person together? And where do you add to `list_of_ids`? Is `list_of_animals` supposed to be the same? In your example data, would all records with "id" `HO222222222222` have to stay together and go into the same file? Is it possible for there to be records with `HO222222222222` further on in the file, or will they be together in the source file?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I edited errors in example. Of course it's list_of_ids not animals. And rather all IDs in source files are grouped, so they are together. Now my script divide a big file to 4 smaller where in for example firts file I have first 1050 person.

Comment: You're calling `open(a, "a")` many many times without closing it...

Comment: OK, I assumed that I open it, and override that open by next open, but If I understand correctly I just open it 4xxx times without any close? @JohnGordon

Comment: Note that opening the file for each line is very expensive because it perform a system call. In fact 3 system calls. Each system call takes generally at least few micro-seconds. So performing about a billion of system calls is insanely slow. Not to mention closing a file will cause a flush (the file should be closed automatically because of reference counting).

Comment: Please reduce file accessing time first. You are reading line by line in processing. reading and writing line by line should take more time than processing and then saving at once after reading all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
# this number is arbitrary, of course
ids_per_file = 1000
# use with, so the file always closes when you're done, or something happens
with open('20220317_EuroG_MD_v3_XT_POL_FinalReport.txt', 'r') as f:
    # an easier way to loop over all the lines:
    n = 0
    ids = set()
    try:
        for line in f:
            try:
                ids.add(line.split(',')[1])
            except IndexError:
                # you don't want to break, you just want to ignore the line and continue
                continue
            # when the number ids reaches the limit (or at the start), start a new file
            if not n or len(ids) > ids_per_file:
                # close the previous one, unless it's the first
                if n > 0:
                    out_f.close()
                # on to the next
                n += 1
                out_f = open(f'out{n}.csv', 'w')
                # reset ids
                ids = {line.split(',')[1]}
            # write the line, if you get here, it's a record
            out_f.write(line)
    finally:
        # close the last file
        out_f.close()
```

Edit: actually had a bug, would write the first new identifier to the previous file, think this is better.